# Getting count of rows from every month of this year

Tags: mysql, outer-join

Now my question is simple I have many rows in mysql for instance

```
name    created_at
A       2017-05-1
B       2017-05-1
C       2017-06-2
```

Now I have ran this query

```
SELECT MONTH(created_at) , COUNT(created_at) 
FROM invoices
WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
```

This gives me correct result that is

```
5    2
6    1
```

But I also want statistics of previous months too like

```
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    2
6    1
```

How can I modify my querY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a table of months 1 to 12:

```
CREATE TABLE months (month INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO months (month) 
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12);
```

Then use OUTER JOIN to join it to your result:

```
SELECT m.month, COALESCE(i.count, 0) AS count
FROM months AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(created_at) AS month, COUNT(created_at) AS count
    FROM invoices
    WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
) AS i ON m.month = i.month
```